# printf and fgets don't remove the line break

Tags: c

When I put `"four"` in after the first `printf`, then I can't write in the second `printf`.

Why does this happen?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char buffer[5]= {0};
    char buffer2[5]= {0};

    printf("Put your name: "); //i put four
    fgets(buffer,sizeof(buffer),stdin);
    size_t len = strlen(buffer)-1;

    if (buffer[len] == '\n')
        buffer[len] = '\0';

    printf("Put your second name: ");
    fgets(buffer2,sizeof(buffer2),stdin);
    printf("%s",buffer2);
}
```

Comment: Please see [Removing trailing newline character from fgets() input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693776/removing-trailing-newline-character-from-fgets-input/28462221#28462221)

Comment: Perhaps your first and second names are longer than 3 characters (5 to include newline and string terminator). If the first is longer, the excess won't be thrown away but read into the second `fgets`. Don't be mean with your buffer size.

Comment: As I understand it you are entering a 4-character name first, such as **four** and so as the buffer has only 5 (incl terminator) the trailing newline is read as the second input, so of  course the second `printf` does not show anything.

Comment: `size_t len = strlen(buffer)-1;` strlen() can return zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I put "four" in after the first printf, then I can't write in the second printf.

The user is not only typing <kbd>f</kbd><kbd>o</kbd><kbd>u</kbd><kbd>r</kbd>, but also <kbd>enter</kbd>.  So the true *line* of input is 5 characters of `"four\n"`.

The following code will only read 4 characters into `buffer[5]`, leave the `'\n"` in `stdin` for the next `fgets()`.   `fgets()`  read one less than 5 to leave  room for the appended *null character*.

```
char buffer[5]= {0};
fgets(buffer,sizeof(buffer),stdin);
```

---

Avoid too small a buffer, instead recommend 2x the largest expected size.  E.g. [longest name](http://www.historyrundown.com/top-5-people-with-the-longest-names/)

```
#define NAME_MAX 585
#define BUF_SIZE ((NAME_MAX + 1 /* \n */ + 1 /* \0 */)*2)
char buffer[BUF_SIZE] = {0};
printf("Put your name: ");  
if (fgets(buffer,sizeof buffer,stdin)) {
  // process buffer only if `fgets()` succeeds
```

---

Avoid a hacker exploit.  The following is certainly UB should the nefarious user enter a *null character* as the first character.  <kbd>Ctrl @</kbd><kbd>o</kbd><kbd>u</kbd><kbd>r</kbd><kbd>enter</kbd>.

```
size_t len = strlen(buffer)-1;
if (buffer[len] == '\n')
```

Instead

```
size_t len = strlen(buffer);
if (len > 0 && buffer[len-1] == '\n') {
  buffer[--len] = '\0';
}

// Now use `buffer and `len`
```